# How can i get the thermal data from a dji mavic 2 enterprise image?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to get the thermal image data from a photo taken with mavic 2 enterprise.

I ran exiftool on the thermal image and i can't find the thermal data.

[image: Thermal image taken by mavic 2 enterprise]

I expect to find the following fields (espicially Raw Thermal Image binary data)

> ```
> Raw Thermal Image Width         : 640
> Raw Thermal Image Height        : 512
> Raw Thermal Image Type          : TIFF
> Raw Thermal Image               : (Binary data 655564 bytes, use -b option to extract)
> Emissivity                      : 1.00
> Object Distance                 : 2.00 m
> Reflected Apparent Temperature  : 22.0 C
> Atmospheric Temperature         : 22.0 C
> IR Window Temperature           : 22.0 C
> IR Window Transmission          : 1.00
> Relative Humidity               : 50.0 %
> Planck R1                       : 366545
> Planck B                        : 1428
> Planck F                        : 1
> Atmospheric Trans Alpha 1       : 0.000000
> Atmospheric Trans Alpha 2       : 0.000000
> Atmospheric Trans Beta 1        : 0.000000
> Atmospheric Trans Beta 2        : 0.000000
> Atmospheric Trans X             : 0.000000
> Camera Temperature Range Max    : 120.0 C
> Camera Temperature Range Min    : -40.0 C
> Camera Temperature Max Clip     : 99727.0 C
> Camera Temperature Min Clip     : -273.1 C
> Camera Temperature Max Warn     : 99727.0 C
> Camera Temperature Min Warn     : -273.1 C
> Camera Temperature Max Saturated: 99727.0 C
> Camera Temperature Min Saturated: -273.1 C
> ```

Comment: Hi @mrdyrden were you able to extract the thermal data from image?

Comment: Apparently dji mavic enterprise dual does not save the thrermal information, i was informed that dji mavic enterprise advanced does provide the thermal data - i will update this thread once i'll have the results.

Comment: Dji mavic changed ther format of metadata. Have a loot at this, it should solve the issue otherwise let me know if you need help.
https://github.com/detecttechnologies/thermal_base